# Magento 2: Cannot access admin panel: Front controller reached 100 router match iterations

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I've searched the site for any answers relating to this with Magento2 but cannot find anything which works.

My website works fine on the front end but if I try to access the admin page at /admin the site throws an exception, the exception file contains the error:

Front controller reached 100 router match iterations.

I've not added any custom routes or anything like that.  All I was doing prior to this was adding SSL which seemed to work fine for a while then once I edited a base URL (then changed it back) I've started having these issues.

Hopefully someone can shed some light as I've exhausted nearly all options now bar paying someone to take a look at it.  I've added screenshots of some  core_config_data rows which may be of use.

Also, if I change the web/secure/use_in_adminhtml from 1 to 0.  I get a different error: Too many redirects.  The url seems to keep switching from www. to non-www.

[image: config_core_data]

[image]

Thanks.